Why is the plane two dimensional, even though there is a bijection between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$?
In Wikipedia's "Dimension" entry, it is said that dimension of a space is minimum number of coordinates needed to specify any point in that space.
But then I do not understand why the plane is two dimensional.
It is known that there is a bijection between the points on the plane and the elements of $\mathbb R^2$; also, there is bijection between the elements of $\mathbb R^2$ and the elements of $\mathbb R$.
So I can specify any point on the plane using only one number. Isn't the plane's dimension is one then?
What's the problem in my reasoning?

That is an informal way of thinking about it and not rigorous.

On the Cartesian plane any point needs an x-coordinate and a y-coordinate.  A plane by definition is a flat, 2-dimensional surface that extends infinitely in all directions.  A number line only needs one coordinate because a line is one-dimensional.

@Randall could you please explain where is error in my reasoning if it is possible?

@ArturoMagidin damn, you are right! thank you

The error is not in your reasoning, it's just that the statement of "needing two coordinates" is not made precise enough. You might want to add some smoothness assumption for instance.

In addition to needing to specify the bijection you are using for your scheme to work (sorry for deleting the past comment), note that the Wikipedia page says that this is an informal definition, not a formal one. Any formal definition will not allow you to use such a scheme to "prove" that the dimension is one.

@ArturoMagidin oh, I understood, then the problem here is that the definition is not complete. Then I will try to find more precise definition.

It's not a definition at all. It is an informal description of the notion that we will try to capture with an actual formal definition.

Different branches of math have different notion of dimension. But for the plane, they all agree. The most basic notion of dimension you usually learn when taking a linear algebra class

@MoisheKohan yeah, I also was thinking about it. But I also guessed that maybe geometry has some other kind of definition because geometry is about like points in space and maybe it is more related to topology while linear algebra is just about vector spaces. But from linear algebra perspective plane's dimension is definitely two.

There are many different areas of math called "geometry" and all have at least one notion of dimension (varying greatly between different areas of geimetry). Hardly any refer to "counting the number of coordinares."

The Definition is not very rigorous , which the comments have already shown.
Yet , there is a way to see the error in your thinking , when using valid Definition rectifying the non-rigorousness.
Check that "dimension of a space is minimum number of coordinates needed" talks about co-ordinate , not real numbers.
In other words , it is not "dimension of a space is minimum number of real numbers needed" , hence there is no Contradiction in it.
Yes , you have already said that $P=(x,y)$ are the 2 co-ordinates , using 2 real numbers , which we can map to real number $z$ , though that is still 2 co-ordinates. We require a way to "split" $z$ into $(x,y)$ to know the 2 $P$ co-ordinates.
We can think that while $P$ is $(x,y)$ , $z$ is the encoding for $(x,y)$ , which has to be decoded.
Additionally , we might require the 2 co-ordinates $P=(x,y)$ to have continuity , limits , order , neighborhood , metric + what-not. Those are missing in $z$ , because it is not a co-ordinate.
Thus , there is no Contradiction in the Plane Dimension , whether we use Single real number or Double real numbers : the Plane has Dimension $2$ always requiring $2$ Co-ordinates.

do I understand correctly that in your answer you think about coordinates from linear algebra perspective?

Yes , it is linear algebra way where $W=(x,y)$ is a tuple while the norm $|W|$ is a real number which has converted the 2 real numbers to Single real number. Here there is no way to get back the Original 2 numbers. In your Bijection , we can always get back the 2 numbers when we are given Single Encoded real number. Hence we always have 2 co-ordinates.

OK, so my conclusion regarding my question is that wikipedia's intuitive description of dimension of space is not precise enough. One possible definition of dimension is linear algebra's one, where it is defined as maximum number of independent vectors. Then plane's dimension is two because we can consider plane as set of ordered pairs (x,y) in some coordinate system, and these pairs form vector space. And there are no vector space with fewer dimension which would be isomorphic to this vector space. So we always need two vectors in our basis for plane.

Correct. More-over there are many ways to convert $n$ real numbers to Single real number , eg various norm values. Some ( not all ) of those ways can be inverted to get back the $n$ real Numbers. None of the ways preserve interesting properties like continuity + metrics + order.

The Wikipedia-article is a bit too informal. In the introductory section it only gives an idea what the concept of "dimension" is - it has to do something with "coordinates". It does not make precise what a coordinate is and which values coordinates can take: Real numbers, complex numbers, integers or something else?
Your example is correct - you can describe points of the plane by a single real parameter. But this example only shows that there is no reasonable concept of dimension for sets. We need more structure to define dimension.
The classical example of dimension is the dimension of a vector space (over a given ground field $K$). Coordinates are introduced via bases. It is well-known that if a given basis $B$ has $n$ elements, then all bases have $n$ elements. Therefore there exists a unique number $n$ such that each element $v$ of the vector space can be described by $n$ parameters, or coordinates, $a_i$ in the ground field ($v = \sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i$ with $a_i \in K$, where $B  = \{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$). In other words, the basis elements elements $b_i$ give a coordinate system in $V$.
It is the structure of a vector space which makes the concept work. In your example $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$ are vector spaces of dimension $1$ and $2$, but a bijection $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ of sets cannot be a vector space isomorphism so that $f$ does not provide a one-dimensional coordinate system on $\mathbb R^2$ in the sense of linear algebra.
The Wikipedia-article gives quite a number of dimension-concepts in various areas of mathematics. Some are closely related to vector space dimension (i.e. work with coordinates in a precise sense), some have a completely different spirit and have nothing to do with coordinates in any sense. Some objects can even have a non-integer dimension (e.g. the Hausdorff dimension of fractals).
Observe, however, that all these concepts heavily depend on certain structures which go far beyond sets.
